# Ruby attribute meta programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `user` has the attribute:

```
:step1_local
:step2_local
:step3_local
...
...
:local1
:local2
:local3
```

I would like to change an attribute value based on another set of attributes on the same model. I would like to do some processing mapping on `user`, say:

```
def magic (user)
   user.local(1..3) = process(user.step(1..3)_local)
end
```

The code above of course does not work (example). I am not sure how to do it dynamically without going through each attributes individually. I want to map processing one to another. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) and method, like this:

```
def magic(user)
  (1..3).each do |n|
    user.public_send("local#{n}=", process(user.read_attribute("step#{n}_local")))
  end
end
```